# Google Visualization with json input

Tags: ajax, json, google-visualization

As a beginner I'm struggling with Google Visualization for making charts from the JSON file inputs. I have searched similar questions but I wasn't sure it helps.

I have a set of data in JSON format. Currently it is static data and is stored locally. I want to load the data and visualize it using Google visualization. My data is like this:

```
     "rows":[{"Time":10:00:00,"Lat":53.02900044,"Long":7.44578671,"Altitude":57,"Speed":0,...}, {"Time": 11:00:00,"Lat":52.06000044,"Long":7.54578671,"Altitude":53,"Speed":12,...]}
```

I try to use this way:

```
    function init () {

var json3 = (function () {
    var json3 = [];
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "Person3.json",
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data3) {
            json3 = data3.rows;
        }
    });
    console.log("Number of message rows: " + json3.length);
    return json3;
})();
var readings3 = [];
if (json3.length > 0)
    var readings3 = json3;
    else
    readings3=[
        {"Time":"10:00:00 ","Lat":66.02794563,"Long":7.45527353,.....},
        {"Time":"13:40:52 ","Lat":66.16435456,"Long":7.98108809,......}
        ]
var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable(readings3);

var graphview = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'visualization1',

    dataTable: data3,
options: {
        // chart options
    }
});

graphview.draw();    
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:  ['corechart'], callback: init});
```

Can someone help me what is missing here, or if you see similar problems being solved.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable constructor will not accept an object with that structure; you will have to parse that object into a DataTable manually:

```
var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data3.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
data3.addColumn('number', 'Lat');
data3.addColumn('number', 'Long');
//...
for (var i = 0; i < readings3.length; i++) {
    var match = readings3[i].Time.match(/(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
    var hours = parseInt(match[1], 10);
    var minutes = parseInt(match[2], 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(match[3], 10);
    data.addRow([[hours, minutes, seconds, 0], readings3[i].Lat, readings3[i].Long, /* ... */]);
}
```

Also, in the event it isn't a copy/paste error, your times in the JSON string need to be quoted, as `"Time":10:00:00` is not valid.

Comment: Hi Asgallant, it works perfect!!! Thanks. Do you know if the same approach will works as well for a dynamic-realtime JSON data?

Comment: Yes, you can take the same approach.  If your keys are going to change from data set to data set, you should include some metadata for column construction so you can dynamically build those as well.